# Airflow submits same query multiple times

Tags: airflow

We are facing issue in airflow, where it is executing same query multiple times.

We checked that only one instance of DAG is running at that time.
In web UI,checked ran TASK instance but it shows only one task logs.

There are total 4 worker nodes and after Checking worker node logs found out that,
Worker Node 1: DML TASK executed by this worker node at 01.00
Worker Node 2: No DML executed but only Queuing attempt 1 at 01.00
Worker Node 3: No task run on this node at at 01.00
Worker Node 4: Same  DML TASK executed by this worker node at 01.00

Worker Node 1 and Node 4 submitted same DML to sever at same time.

Any way to avoid airflow from submitting same query multiple times by different worker nodes?

Comment: By query, do you mean it's executing a task multiple times in a single DAG run? What type of operator is it? Any clues in the task logs that it's been run more than once?

Comment: We observed this issue in BashOperator and PythonOperator.
BashOperator Issue:
 As per our requirement we want to run the DAG in loop, so we use 'CURL' command in bashoperator to trigger same DAG using rest API and we observed that DAG is triggered multiple times by bashoperator.
 
PythonOperator:
 We are executing some SQLs and found out that same sql query is submitted to server twice by airflow.

Comment: We ran ' airflow backfil ' command for few dags after that we started facing this issue.can 'airflow backfill ' command cause of this issue?